# Timing CUDA Streams

Tags: cuda

I'm having some trouble understanding this code (running on non-Hyper-Q compatible GPU):

```
CHECK(cudaEventRecord(start, 0));

// dispatch job with depth first ordering
for (int i = 0; i < n_streams; i++)
{
    kernel_1<<<grid, block, 0, streams[i]>>>();
    kernel_2<<<grid, block, 0, streams[i]>>>();
    kernel_3<<<grid, block, 0, streams[i]>>>();
    kernel_4<<<grid, block, 0, streams[i]>>>();
}

// record stop event
CHECK(cudaEventRecord(stop, 0));
CHECK(cudaEventSynchronize(stop));

// calculate elapsed time
CHECK(cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed_time, start, stop));
printf("Measured time for parallel execution = %.3fs\n",
       elapsed_time / 1000.0f);
```

The entire program can also be found [here](https://github.com/deeperlearning/professional-cuda-c-programming/blob/master/chapter06/simpleHyperqDepth.cu#L134).

The question is: How can we be sure that all other kernels are complete before calculating the elapsed time?

There doesn't seem to be any synchronization between the non-Null stream and the other streams launched. Even if the stop event is the last one on the queue, based on my understanding it seems possible that other kernels from other streams are still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in Professional CUDA C Programming:

> Events specified on the default stream apply to all preceding operations in all CUDA streams.

In other words, events in the default, non-NULL stream complete after all preceding operations in all streams have completed.